# How to calculate average value?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

I have two tables. Into the first table (activity) there are: user_id, sessions and login_time. Into the second (payments) there's only one column - user_id.

I need to calculate how many sessions did users from "payments" do during 01/01/2018-01/05/2018.

```
activity

user_id   sessions   login_time
1           6         01.01.2018
2           2         01.01.2018
1           1         02.01.2018
4           3         02.01.2018
1           2         03.05.2018
3                     04.02.2018
```

table

```
payments
user_id
1
3
4
```

My code (calculates wrong):

```
select login_time, avg(activity.sessions) AS
average_sessions
from activity inner join
payments
on payments.user_id = activity.user_id
where activity.login_time between '2018-01-01' and '2018-05-01' 
group by activity.login_time;
```

Thanks for help!

Output:

```
output
login_time    average_sessions
01.01.2018     6
02.01.2018     2
03.01.2018     0
04.01.2018     0
...
```

Comment: Give your expected output as well! Question is bit unclear without expected output

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya, I updated

Comment: Are you trying to calculate average session per user ?

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya, yes. Per user from second table

Comment: Replace `avg(activity.sessions)` With `SUM(activity.sessions)/COUNT(DISTINCT activity.user_id)`

Comment: Also, your expected output is wrong. Can you give it in table output format, based on your given input data.

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya, updated

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52137316/2469308

Answer (score 1):

looking to  your sample
seems  you need  the sum of session divided by the number of totals days

```
  select  user_id, sum(sessions)/t.num_days
  from activity 
  cross join  (
  select count(distinct login_time) num_days
  from activity
  ) t 
  group by user_id
```

and if you need  only the user_id in payments

```
  select  user_id, sum(sessions)/t.num_days
  from activity 
  cross join  (
  select count(distinct login_time) num_days
  from activity
  ) t 
  inner join  payments p on p.user_id = activity.user_id
  group by user_id
```

and looking to  your formaed  result  seems you need

```
  select t1. login_time, ifnull(t2.avg_sess) average_sessions
  from (
  select distinct login_time 
  from activity 
  ) t1  
  left join (
  select a.login_time, avg(a.session) avg_sess
  from activity a
  inner join payments p on a.user_id  = p.user_id
  group by a.login_time
  ) t2 on t1.login_time = t2.login_time
```

Comment: thanks, but I need to calculate average session per user only from second table by dates. How can I do it?

Comment: ok, but I need a two column table. One column is date (01/04/2018, 02/04/2018...) and other column - is quantity of sessions only for users from payments.
Please, answer

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков  asnwer  updated .. based on your result  .. hope is waht you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Based on your expected output, use the following:

```
SELECT login_time, 
       SUM(activity.sessions)/COUNT(DISTINCT activity.user_id) AS average_sessions
FROM activity 
INNER JOIN payments ON payments.user_id = activity.user_id
WHERE activity.login_time BETWEEN '2018-01-01' and '2018-05-01' 
GROUP BY activity.login_time;
```

Comment: thanks. But I think it searches average value from all user sessions, but I need to search among sessions only from second table.

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков It does for sessions from second table users only, because of the `INNER JOIN`. It restricts the sessions to be considered only from the `payments` table users.

Comment: could you explain why avg() and "SUM(activity.sessions)/COUNT(DISTINCT activity.user_id)" in this case give different result?

Comment: DISTINCT ensures that user_id is not counted multiple times, in case of having multiple rows for a user_id in the activity table.

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков I just checked that your original query is also giving results, as per your expected output. So what exactly is the issue ?

Comment: in reality I have 9000 row table. And checked my resuld in Excel. But have got result that differs from sql result. I don't know why.

For example 05/04/2018 there were 2000 users, which iniciated 9000 sessions.
But in second table there were 200 users only, which iniciated 1000 sessions.

I devide 1000 / 200. Is it right?

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков yes you are right. Can you try with my query; maybe there is some duplicate data, which is being missed in the sample data for this question

Comment: Excel shows me that must be 5 session on average. But with your query sql gives me 28 sessions. May be there's a necessity to add into query additional data restriction?

Comment: Now I tested different variants. A trouble os in part of query "SUM(activity.sessions)", I think

Comment: can u share the PK/Unique key constraints on the two tables ? That will help in figuring out if data can be duplicate

Comment: I have 3 tables (users, activity and payments)
users has PK - id, activity has user_id as FK and no PK, payments  also has user_id as FK and no PK.

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков so basically there is definitely duplicate data based on user_id and login_time in activity table, and possibly duplicate user_id data in payments table as well; my query calculates based on unique users, but there is a chance of duplication of sessions calculation (due to duplicate data possibility). Try to put a unique constraint on user_id AND login_time in activity table; you will get errors with information on all the duplicate entries

Comment: Is it right to find only payment id sessions? SELECT activity.login_time, sum(activity.sessions) FROM activity 
inner JOIN payments ON payments.user_id = activity.user_id
WHERE activity.login_time BETWEEN '2018-04-05' and '2018-04-18' 
GROUP BY activity.login_time;

Comment: But this can have duplicates, so SUM will not be right. You may have duplicate value of user_id(s) in payments table also

Comment: you are right. I did this query (from my previous comment). And now I am sure, that there are duplicate users in table 'payments'.

Please, can U tell me how can I change this query to avoid duplicate users from "payments'?

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков It is a database design problem. You will have put UNIQUE constraint on the user_id in payments table. First remove duplicates, and then put the constraint